# Defining custom error messages in controller in Laravel 5.2

Tags: validation, controller, laravel-5

I need to do validation in one of my controllers — I can't use a request class for this particular issue — so I'm trying to figure out how to define custom validation messages in the controller. I've looked all over and can't find anything that suggests it's possible. Is it possible? How would I do it?

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

    // Can I create custom error messages for each input down here? Like...
    $this->validate($errors, [
        'title' => 'Please enter a title',
        'body' => 'Please enter some text',
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a request class like below. message overwrite is what you are looking for.

```
class RegisterRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'UserName'      =>  'required|min:5|max:50',
            'Password'      =>  'required|confirmed|min:5|max:100',

        ];
    }

    public function response(array $errors){
        return \Redirect::back()->withErrors($errors)->withInput();
    }

    //This is what you are looking for
    public function messages () {
        return [
            'FirstName'  => 'Only alphabets allowed in First Name',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use a request class for this particular issue, it has to be done in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

This did it

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'title'  => 'required',
    'body'   => 'required',
], [
    'title.required' => 'Please enter a title',
    'body.required'  => 'Please enter some text',
]);
```